# alternative to datatables in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking for a nice alternative to datatables.

All it should do is a simple form where people can enter a string and it should filter all the results and display them to the user.

If you know a good alternative and it's not a gem this is also ok.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

and a code example here http://select-2-example.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Had to wait a few days for an answer but that's totally worth it. thanks mate !

Comment: Haha, I actually answered you within an hour (iirc)  glad I could help.